# write sqlite data to html file and email html file as attachment

Tags: android, html, sqlite

In my application,I have to send sqlite data in Html file as report,means I have write sqlite data to html file,after that this html file should be attach as attachment in email.right now I am sending sqlite data using emailIntent.putExtra method Htmlf format.But this should go as message to mail.but I want some file like html to save on my device.or create new html file and write sqlite data to it,and send as attachment.

Comment: You cannot write to assets but you can write a regular file. Please pay attention to question quality. For example, demonstrate what you've tried and what is the specific problem.

Comment: @laalto...Thanks man..can save html file to other location or create html file and write some data into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code: just take the sql data and store as String and write it using OutputStreamWriter and add the file as an attachment

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    String data = "<html><body> My name is John.</body></html>";
    String uri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"";

    File f = new File(uri,"san.html");
    if(!f.exists()){
        try {
               f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream fout;
    try {
        fout = openFileOutput(uri,MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout); 
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent emailintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailintent.setType("text/html");
        emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(f));
        emailintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(f));                      
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the Attachments");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent, "Email:"));
    }   
}
```

Comment: jadhav...Thank you so much...for given good answer..But its give error at this line **fout = openFileOutput(uri,MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);** as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /mnt/sdcard/san.html contains a path separator

Comment: please change this lines                                           String uri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"";
File f = new File(uri,"san.html");                                               in code and add the permissions to your "androidmanifestfile"and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: sandip...now i change code but attachment not send it gives problem

Comment: emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(f));
emailintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);           JUST ADD THIS PERMISSION AND CHANGE ONE LINE Uri.parse to Uri.fromFile() if there are any difficulties let me know